# Use of with for getting flashed messages in flask

Tags: python, flask

I was checking the message flashing in flask framework from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_message_flashing.htm).

This is a basic example where a template file (*Index.html*) is used to provide the initial link and another template file (*Login.html*) creates the form.

The files are:

**Login.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <h1>Login</h1>

      {% if error %}
      <p><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
      {% endif %}

      <form action = "" method = post>
         <dl>
            <dt>Username:</dt>

            <dd>
               <input type = text name = username 
                  value = "{{request.form.username }}">
            </dd>

            <dt>Password:</dt>
            <dd><input type = password name = password></dd>
         </dl>
         <p><input type = submit value = Login></p>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

**Index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Flask Message flashing</title>
   </head>
   <body>

      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
         {% if messages %}
            <ul>
               {% for message in messages %}
               <li<{{ message }}</li>
               {% endfor %}
            </ul>
         {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}

      <h1>Flask Message Flashing Example</h1>
      <p>Do you want to <a href = "{{ url_for('login') }}">
         <b>log in?</b></a></p>

   </body>
</html>
```

**Flash.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'random string'

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
   error = None

   if request.method == 'POST':
      if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or \
         request.form['password'] != 'admin':
         error = 'Invalid username or password. Please try again!'
      else:
         flash('You were successfully logged in')
         return redirect(url_for('index'))

   return render_template('login.html', error = error)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug = True)
```

The part that is confusing me is inside *index.html*. It's using `with messages = get_flashed_messages()` to get the messages from the session. I do not fully understand why it's using `with`? I know `with` is used for resources, files, streams etc to control the closing procedure (and for not leaving something open when something goes wrong etc). What's the resource it's accessing using `with` in this context?

I tried removing it (in this context) and an error occurred:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag
>   'messages'.

Also, example use cases from [programcreek.com](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/58907/flask.get_flashed_messages) does not use `with` with `get_flashed_messages` so what's the case here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jinja templates are not Python. `with` in a template is not a Python context manager, it just introduces a new scope; this code definesa new variable `messages` that is only visible until the `endwith`.

See [the docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#with-statement).

Comment: So, the equivalent without `with` would be by replacing `with` with `set` and deleting `endwith` also

Answer (score -1):

try to fix index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flask Message flashing</title>
</head>
<body>

{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
        <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
                <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

<h1>Flask Message Flashing Example</h1>
<p>Do you want to <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">
    <b>log in?</b></a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add more details.